# SSH alternative for php on very strict security web server

Tags: php, curl, ssh, web-hosting

I have to connect to external server (lets name it server B) inside my php script. The easiest way to do that would be by using SSH2. But ssh2 is blocked due to security reasons and Net_SSH2 doesn't work (probably for the same reasons). And for now I have no possibility to turn SSH on, or change this webhosting. Thankfully cURL is working and I'm thinking about some alternatives.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to just write some perl script on this server B, put it into cgi-bin, then to connect to this script through cURL using some authentication and run some things on server B.

Unfortunately this mean to write some authentication and stuff, there are a lot of potential problems with security and stuff.

Anyone have a better idea how to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: SSH is blocked for security reasons, but you can do anything you want inside a cgi-script?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't write it clearly enough. I have to just run one script on this server B (with some options) and I though about making a cgi-script on this server B (in which it would start this one script with options passed for example through post), visible on a internet, and just connect with this cgi-script

Comment: Why are you saying Net_SSH2 work? What error are you getting? Are you using Net_SSH2 from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ or from http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SSH2 ?